# Unity не могу получить все json файлы из StreamAssets на Android

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

Пытаюсь получить все json файлы из папки StreamAssets на Android использую такой код

```
string filePath = Application.streamingAssetsPath;
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);
FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.json");
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            GameObject catalog = Instantiate(catPrefab) as GameObject;
            catalog.name=Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name).ToString();
            Debug.Log(catalog.name);
        }
```

На Unity эмуляторе все файлы подгружаются все работает нормально, но когда загружаю APK на андроид ни один файл не находит.

поставил проверку на существование файла

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);
    if (!dir.Exists)
    {
         Debug.Log("Нет такого каталога"); 
    }
```

как сделать так чтобы все работало и на Андроиде? Спасибо заранее

Comment: может быть там прав не хватает...... вообще, в качестве приблуды почему бы не написать логику логирования? и в случае warnings или errors писать в лог и отображать это на экране, а не в `Debug.Log`, чтобы можно было самому визуально проанализировать причину? поставить try catch тоже, как полагается и залогировать проблемное место

Comment: К большому сожалению я в этом деле новичок. Я из веб программирования перешел сюда и многое не понятно. Можете по подробнее с кодом написать ?

Comment: @bellator001 Подскажите, пожалуйста, что вы имеете в виду, когда пишите "ни один файл не находит"? Из вашего кода я вижу, что вы выводите имена файлов в дебаг лог, но он дебаг лог - это элемент интерфейса **редактора** юнити. Попробйте выводить имена файлов в элемент UI, например.